# Laravel 5 Apply user localization on API routes

Tags: php, localization, laravel-5.4, laravel-localization

I followed the tutorial from this [link](https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale).
And yeah, it's working great with my web routes. I have 2 supported locales, which are English(en) and Swedish(sv). I save the user's locale selection to the `Session` however, my app mostly consists of ajax requests to the API routes; So my API routes is not affected with what the user's locale selection. How can I set the localization on API routes?

I did something like this on my controller which solved the problem(not sure if it's good to do it this way), but I don't think I'm doing this right since I will be adding this code on my every controller.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
  function __construct() {
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

    if ($user && $user->lang != "") {
        \App::setLocale($user->lang);
    }
} ...
```

I don't know if I am doing right or wrong. How can this solution be improved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about putting that code in the base controller?

Comment: @waterloomatt Thanks, yeah you're right. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a user's locale in the database. The user object would then be fetched on every authenticated request and you can then use the locale from it. If there's no authentication in the api or you need to apply locale to non auth routes, you have to provide the locale in each request. This can be through query string or headers.

Edit : Based on your comment, what you're doing is right. But you need to use closure based middleware to access the authenticated user.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#session-in-the-constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();

        if($user && $user->lang != "" ){
            app()->setLocale($user->lang);
        }

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Comment: I already stored the user's locale on the database and updates it every time the user changes his locale.  I updated my question and added the things that I tried. Can you improved your answer base on my updated question?

Comment: @dexterb what you're doing should work nicely except that you need to use closure based middleware to get the authenticated user in the constructor https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#session-in-the-constructor

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. I've added the code on my base controller and all works well now.